# How to create a global generic class which implements a generic interface?

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit2

To be very honest I need to use Retofit Callback for multiple classes. I dont want to write the callback interface with onResponse and onFailour method in each UI page.

So I decided to write a global class which will implements the Retrofit Callback interface.

But my problem is, I want to make it Generic, because there are many different ResponseParser classes which are going to use this global class.

I tried like below, but facing a little problem in it.

```
public class WebAPIControler implements Callback<TResponse>{

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<TResponse> call, Response<TResponse> response) {

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<TResponse> call, Throwable t) {

}
}
```

Here compiler not able to found *TResponse* class. here TResponse is a generic class where I want to handle all king of ResponseParser classes. So I give a name it as T or TResponse. Please help me how to handle this.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `public class WebAPIController<TResponse> implements Callback<TResponse>`, so that `TResponse` will be a generic type parameter of the class `WebAPIController`

Comment: Yes, kind of this. but can you help me little that how to use this or suppose I want to pass ABCResponseParser  to WebAPIControler class. How I will handle this by the help of T or TResponse.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your class as generic class first then implement generic interface.

```
public class WebAPIControler implements Callback<T>{

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

}
}
```

> What is T?

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

I suggest you just implement generic interface, your class is not required to be generic.

**UPDATE**

a.create Interface

```
interface CustomSubscriber<T>  {
void test(T object);
}
```

b.Implement your interface with any object

```
public class WebAPIControler implements CustomSubscriber<JsonObject>{

@Override
public void test(JsonObject object) {

}
}
```

Comment: thanks Aks. But when I am writing  Callback<T> or  Callback<TResponse>, its throwing red error that TResponse is not found etc as it not a class..so do I have to right a base class for all Response classes  and extends in TResponse like Callback<T extends All_Response_Parser_Base_Class>

Comment: Or its like public class public class WebAPIControler<T extends All_Response_Parser_Base_Class> implements Callback<T> implements Callback<T extends All_Response_Parser_Base_Class>

Comment: I am updating my answer. pls check

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, what you're missing is the generic type declaration in `public class WebAPIControler<T>`. That's why the compiler is complaining T doesn't exist.

```
public class WebAPIControler<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. Can I call this class like `WebAPIControler w = new WebAPIControler(); ` Or I have to follow any generic rules for it

Comment: You would instantiate it like this: `WebAPIControler<SomeClass> w = new WebAPIControler<>();`. That will create an instance of WebAPIControler where `T` was replaced by `SomeClass`.

Comment: great..let me check once